# Instant Run Crashes Every Time Unless ReRun Is Called (onActivityCreated Callback Issue)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-lifecycle, android-instant-run

I have an `Activity` that has a `Fragment` member.

In the `Fragment` I have some view objects that the `Activity` needs to access. As such the `Activity` needs to know when the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView` is finished.

To accomplish this I have setup a callback to fire in the `Fragment`'s `onActivityCreated` (which I know is called AFTER `onViewCreated` and when the view the `Activity` wants, in this case a button, will not be null).

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (_didLoadCallback != null)
    {
        _didLoadCallback.callback();
    }
}
```

And in my `Activity` I create the fragment and set its callback:

```
private void initFragment()
{
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    _fragment = MyFragmentClass.newInstance(new Callbacks.VoidCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void callback()
        {
            continueInitializationAfterFragmentLoaded();
        }
    });

    fragmentTransaction.add(_root.getId(), _startWorkoutFragment);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
}
```

And the reason I need to have this hook, as mentioned, the `Activity` needs access to view objects inside the `Fragment`.

In my `Fragment` I have an object that I access with a getter:

```
public Button getButton()
{
    return _button;
}
```

And this button is created in the `onCreateView`.

When I run the program the first time or from a rerun, this works perfectly. However when I hit instant run again, the program crashes as the `getButton` returns a null.

Further adding to my confusion is I logged the events in order to make sure my object wasn't null, and oddly enough, with instant-run only (not with re-runs), the `getButton` returns a not null the first time its called (in the `onCreateView` in the `Fragment`)  but then when it fires the callback to the `Activity`, the `getButton` call suddenly returns null!

> D/Log: co.myapp.app.Widgets.Button{84ba583 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} (Fragment `onCreateView`)
>
> D/Log: null
>   (Activity after didLoad callback trying to access button)

But yet when I do a rerun (or a full build) it works:

> D/Log: co.myapp.app.Widgets.Button{b0b44a0 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
>   (Fragment `onCreateView`)
>
> D/Log: co.myapp.app.Widgets.Button{b0b44a0 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
>   (Activity after didLoad callback trying to access button)

Do you have any idea whats going on? Or maybe what I've done wrong with my initialization callback hook?

**Update** I even verify the button is not null before firing the callback and it still crashes?!

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (_didLoadCallback != null && getButton() != null)
    {
        _didLoadCallback.callback();
    }
}
```